# primeng does not show card

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular. Even though I import the card module, the card cannot be displayed.

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/accordion'
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';

import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { CardModule, } from 'primeng/card';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CardModule,
    ButtonModule,
    AccordionModule
    ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

[image]

I used the latest versions but still can't find the error

```
<p-card header="Simple Card" [style]="{'width': '25rem', 'margin-bottom': '2em'}">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore sed consequuntur error repudiandae numquam deserunt
      quisquam repellat libero asperiores earum nam nobis, culpa ratione quam perferendis esse, cupiditate neque quas!</p>
</p-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Get Started

You have probably not added the css for primeng.

You can check [how to get started](https://primeng.org/setup) on the official website.

You should probably start with the section on 'Styles' and add this to your `angular.json`:

```json
"styles": [
    "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
    "node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css",
    "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    ...
]
```

### Version

Also make sure to use the right version, PrimeNG v15 (the latest version) is meant for Angular 15. If you are worling on an Angular 14 project, use PrimeNG v14.*

You can get the right documentation for the version you are using on the official website by selecting the right version in the top right corner. *(Apparently this is currently not working as expected, at least for me, at the time of this writing.)*

### Examples

Since you said you want to use the latest version (15.2.0), here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i2kj43?file=src/main.ts) using angular 15.

And in this [other StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lk7isi?file=src/app/app.component.html) you can find an example using a module file instead of standalone components in angular 14, as per your codeblock in the question.

Comment: thank you, but ı added  styles. but still not working

Comment: I added another suggestion to the answer. I'm just going through the obvious mistakes you could be making, given the limited information you have given us.

Comment: thanks, i solved problem. As you said, there is a problem with the version.